Amount of Mahr fixed After wedding . Valid marriage?
Salam aleykum,
I hope you are well.
I had my religious marriage (after a civil marriage) with the imam of a mosque.
My guardian and my two Muslim witnesses were there.
The imam asked us if we had agreed on the dowry; we didn't know how to answer because my husband and I hadn't set an amount, but the imam continued with the ceremony.
The day before the wedding my husband asked me how much I wanted as a dowry, I told him we'd see on the day of the wedding but we didn't. Personally, I'm planning to ask for a dowry in the future.
Personally, I intend to ask for a simple dowry (according to his means) but my husband doesn't know (we haven't discussed it).
My question: Is the marriage valid even if we had no idea of the amount of the dowry while the imam was marrying us?
WE will fix ( me and my husband) the amount later.
Thank you for your help.
Salam aleykum

Your question is already answered, and with references, too. Just an additional advice: fix the mehr soon. As years come, this should not be an issue to quarrel about later.  Just look at the western media about the rich and the beauty when it comes to divorce ... really ugly stuff, but it just happens some times, somewhere, for someone. I hope you never see this ugly stuff but just be happy with your husband and your children.

Thank you so much. God bless you

It will be a valid marriage, even if the Mahr was not fixed at the time of the contract.
The Quran permits divorce before fixing mahr and that itself implies that marriage can be done without fixing mahr as divorce only occurs after marriage:

لا جناح عليكم إن طلقتم النساء ما لم تمسوهن أو تفرضوا لهن فريضة ومتعوهن على الموسع قدره وعلى المقتر قدره متاعا بالمعروف حقا على المحسنين
There is no blame upon you if you divorce women you have not touched nor specified for them an obligation (mahr). But give them [a gift of] compensation - the wealthy according to his capability and the poor according to his capability - a provision according to what is acceptable, a duty upon the doers of good.
— Quran 2:236

And it is also evident from the Sunnah and Ijma:

عن عقبة بن عامر، أن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم قال لرجل ‏"‏ أترضى أن أزوجك فلانة ‏"‏ ‏.‏ قال نعم ‏.‏ وقال للمرأة ‏"‏ أترضين أن أزوجك فلانا ‏"‏ ‏.‏ قالت نعم ‏.‏ فزوج أحدهما صاحبه فدخل بها الرجل ولم يفرض لها صداقا ولم يعطها شيئا وكان ممن شهد الحديبية وكان من شهد الحديبية له سهم بخيبر فلما حضرته الوفاة قال إن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم زوجني فلانة ولم أفرض لها صداقا ولم أعطها شيئا وإني أشهدكم أني أعطيتها من صداقها سهمي بخيبر فأخذت سهما فباعته بمائة ألف
Uqbah ibn Amir:
The Prophet (ﷺ) said to a man: Would you like me to marry you to
so-and-so?
He said: Yes. He also said to the woman: Would you like me to marry
you to so-and-so?
She said: Yes. He then married one to the other. The man had sexual
intercourse with her, but he did not fix any dower for her, nor did he
give anything to her. He was one of those who participated in the
expedition to al-Hudaybiyyah. One part of the expedition to
al-Hudaybiyyah had a share in Khaybar.
When he was nearing his death, he said: The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ)
married me to so-and-so, and I did not fix a dower for her, nor did I
give anything to her. I call upon you as witness that I have given my
share in Khaybar as her dower. So she took the share and sold it for
one hundred thousand (of dirhams).
— Abu Dawud


ولا خلاف في أن النكاح يصح من غير ذكر المهر
It is agreed that marriage is valid without mention of mahr
— Bada'i al-Sana'i


Thank you so much. God bless you  it is very clear.
